# Can't share using OAuth Starter Kit for LinkedIn

Tags: ios, oauth, linkedin-api

I use OAuthStarter Kit for accessing the LinkedIn API. I get an access token successfully for the permissions.

> **rw_ns**
> **r_basicprofile**
> **r_fullprofile**

It is possible to get the profile details as well as to share only comments and while sharing URL or image or description etc... I using following code:

```
-(void)postUpdate
 {
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares"];
   OAMutableURLRequest *request =
   [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url
                            consumer:[self getConsumer]
                               token:self.accesstoken
                            callback:nil
                   signatureProvider:nil];

   NSDictionary *update = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                    
                    [[NSDictionary alloc]
                     initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                     @"anyone",@"code",nil], @"visibility",
                    @"title goes here",@"title",
                    @"comment goes here", @"comment",
                    @"description goes here",@"description",
                     @"www.google.com",@"submitted-url",
                    @"http://economy.blog.ocregister.com/files/2009/01/linkedin-logo.jpg",@"submitted-image-url",
                    nil];
   [request setValue:@"json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"x-li-format"];
   [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

   NSString *updateString = [update JSONString];
   [request setHTTPBodyWithString:updateString];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

   OADataFetcher *fetcher = [[OADataFetcher alloc] init];
   [fetcher fetchDataWithRequest:request
                 delegate:self
        didFinishSelector:@selector(postUpdateApiCallResult:didFinish:)
          didFailSelector:@selector(postUpdateApiCallResult:didFail:)];

  }
```

But I get a response error as follows:

```
 2012-10-09 18:27:29.906 SocialConnectTest[9460:19a03] data {
 "errorCode": 0,
 "message": "Invalid xml {Expected elements 'post-network-update@http://api.linkedin.com/v1 id@http://api.linkedin.com/v1 visibility@http://api.linkedin.com/v1 comment@http://api.linkedin.com/v1 attribution@http://api.linkedin.com/v1 content@http://api.linkedin.com/v1 private-message@http://api.linkedin.com/v1 share-target-reach@http://api.linkedin.com/v1' instead of 'submitted-url@http://api.linkedin.com/v1' here in element share@http://api.linkedin.com/v1}",
 "requestId": "W2G7WJDHOJ",
 "status": 400,
 "timestamp": 1349787449685
}
```

I don't know what the problem is. How can I go about solving this?

Comment: It looks like the endpoint is expecting XML, even though you have specified JSON. Have you tried pushing XML to see if the error is the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i fixed it. 
The problems is in the post parameters

1. As per the documentation of Linked in api,*if we use JSON in request body 
   then keys of post params must be in **camel case**, while in xml  **"-"** seperated key names are used*.
2. Share parameter like **submittedUrl , subsubmittedImageUrl , description,title **etc. must be values of key called **content**.

so i modified the code as follows..

```
-(void)postUpdateHERE
{
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares"];
  OAMutableURLRequest *request =
  [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url
                            consumer:[self getConsumer]
                               token:self.accesstoken
                            callback:nil
                   signatureProvider:nil];

  NSDictionary *update = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:

                    [[NSDictionary alloc]
                     initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                     @"anyone",@"code",nil], @"visibility",

                    @"comment goes here", @"comment",
                    [[NSDictionary alloc]
                     initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                    @"description goes here",@"description",
                    @"www.google.com",@"submittedUrl",
                      @"title goes here",@"title",
                    @"http://economy.blog.ocregister.com/files/2009/01/linkedin-logo.jpg",@"submittedImageUrl",nil],@"content",
                    nil];
  [request setValue:@"json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"x-li-format"];
  [request setValue:@"application/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
  NSString *updateString = [update JSONString];
  [request setHTTPBodyWithString:updateString];
  [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
  OADataFetcher *fetcher = [[OADataFetcher alloc] init];
  [fetcher fetchDataWithRequest:request
                 delegate:self
        didFinishSelector:@selector(postUpdateApiCallResult:didFinish:)
          didFailSelector:@selector(postUpdateApiCallResult:didFail:)];

}
```

now the code works for me..

Comment: I tried your code, but it crashes on the OAuth Starter Kit project. From where do you call you `postUpdateHERE` function?

Comment: thats simply a function that can be called when a event happens, can you log and see what causes the crash

Comment: Aromal can you help me with this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20141897/error-like-unlike-and-comment-using-linkedin-rest-api-for-ios

Comment: whether the didfinisslector or didfailselecctor was called ? after the  request?

Comment: can you also comment on my question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23758142/ioslinkedinapi-cant-share-post-with-the-linkedin-api

Comment: @Aromal Sasidharan what is [self getConsumer] ??