# How to post an image to a LinkedIn account using Objective-C code on iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, linkedin-api

I am able to post the comment to LinkedIn but not able to post the `image`. This is the code for posting the comment:

```
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares"];
  OAMutableURLRequest *request = 
        [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url
                                        consumer:self.consumer
                                           token:self.accessToken
                                        callback:nil
                               signatureProvider:nil];
  NSString *postedStr = self.textView.text;
  NSDictionary *update = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                [[NSDictionary alloc] 
                                 initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 @"anyone",@"code",nil], @"visibility", 
                                postedStr, @"comment", nil];
  [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
  NSString *updateString = [update JSONString];
  [request setHTTPBodyWithString:updateString];
  [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
  OADataFetcher *fetcher = [[OADataFetcher alloc] init];
  [fetcher fetchDataWithRequest:request
                        delegate:self
               didFinishSelector:@selector(postUpdateApiCallResult:didFinish:)
                 didFailSelector:@selector(postUpdateApiCallResult:didFail:)];    
    // [self.view addSubview:linkedinView];
   [request release];
```

Any suggestion really appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this bellow code may be its help you:-

```
-(void)postUpdateHERE
{
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares"];
  OAMutableURLRequest *request =
  [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url
                            consumer:[self getConsumer]
                               token:self.accesstoken
                            callback:nil
                   signatureProvider:nil];

  NSDictionary *update = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:

                    [[NSDictionary alloc]
                     initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                     @"anyone",@"code",nil], @"visibility",

                    @"comment goes here", @"comment",
                    [[NSDictionary alloc]
                     initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                    @"description goes here",@"description",
                    @"www.google.com",@"submittedUrl",
                      @"title goes here",@"title",
                    @"http://economy.blog.ocregister.com/files/2009/01/linkedin-logo.jpg",@"submittedImageUrl",nil],@"content",
                    nil];
  [request setValue:@"json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"x-li-format"];
  [request setValue:@"application/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
  NSString *updateString = [update JSONString];
  [request setHTTPBodyWithString:updateString];
  [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
  OADataFetcher *fetcher = [[OADataFetcher alloc] init];
  [fetcher fetchDataWithRequest:request
                 delegate:self
        didFinishSelector:@selector(postUpdateApiCallResult:didFinish:)
          didFailSelector:@selector(postUpdateApiCallResult:didFail:)];

}
```

i found this from bellow stackover flow answer:-

[Can't share using OAuth Starter Kit for LinkedIn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12801187/cant-share-using-oauth-starter-kit-for-linkedin)

**EDIT:-**

For `TamilKing` comment reply. you can get image URL of you currunt Location using Google API. First you need to get you currunt Location Image Like:-

```
NSString *staticMapUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?markers=color:red|%f,%f&%@&sensor=true",lat, log,@"zoom=12&size=114x116"];    //That above staticMapURl NSlog is :http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?markers=color:red|1.282130,103.803131&zoom=12&size=114x116&sensor=true
```

That given you current Location image for example:-

[image]

Now you have to convert this above NSString to NSURL like

```
NSURL *mapUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[staticMapUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

and use this url that you want to share in to LinkedIn. hope that helps you.

Comment: @NitinGohel please help me for linkedin .

Comment: @Nitin Gohel: In this code you use submittedUrl that means we need to submit our image in anywhere. I need to share my local image in LinkedIn it is possible pls help me?

Comment: @NitinGohel: Thanks for your answer. But I need to share image which is taken by the device. Take the image and share it in LinkedIn

Comment: SURL *mapUrl = [NSURL URLWithString using this you have to convert you image document directory path in to url

Comment: what is [self getConsumer] ??

Comment: if you can check the class of https://github.com/jdg/oauthconsumer/blob/master/OAMutableURLRequest.h there is requred OAConsumer you need to provide a consumer. please check full of the example from github

Answer (score 3):

You may need to do more, but for sure you'll need to set the length...

```
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", updateString.length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
```