# Share image/imagelinks on LinkedIn iOS

Tags: ios, linkedin-api

I have used [the Princess Polymath starter kit for LinkedIn](https://github.com/PrincessPolymath/LinkedIn-OAuth-Sample-Client). The sample works fine.

I wish to share image links on for which I used the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410986/how-to-post-an-image-to-a-linkedin-account-using-objective-c-code-on-ios). But when I share an image I get the response as

```
{
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "Can not parse JSON share document.\nRequest body:\n\nError:\nnull",
  "requestId": "MW8AF25JM2",
  "status": 400,
  "timestamp": 1430244725846
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you sending the request? My first inkling is that your request's content-type isn't `application/json`.

Comment: Thankyou for the reply. I have set the content type to application/json.

Comment: Please add your 'json post body' with a sample imageurl as well in the question

Comment: I have added the URL as:     NSString* stringURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Account/GetImage?galleryId=%@&t=%@",kPortalURL, photoGallery.imgPathID, photoDetail.imgTitle];
    NSString* webStringURL = [stringURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    shareURL = [NSURL URLWithString:webStringURL];
    NSLog(@"Share URL is:%@", shareURL);
 and used the code from    here(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410986/how-to-post-an-image-to-a-linkedin-account-using-objective-c-code-on-ios)....Now i get"errorCode": 0,
  "message": "[unauthorized]. OAU: